# SqlServer wedged connection due to network drop

Tags: .net, sql-server, tcp

We have two directly related problems that can be reduced to a very simple piece of code.
Suppose machine 1 hosts the application, and machine 2 hosts the database, connected by ethernet via a hub.
We are going to simulate network problems by unplugging network cables from the hub.

You would probably say "make your network reliable". So do I. I need to prove it's not first by explicit capture of the problem before the customers will believe.

We cannot solve this problem with timeouts as we have some /very/ long running queries and non-queries. Yes, some of them really do take an hour or more, and users won't put up with staring at a frozen session long enough to get the real error. They kill it instead.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class test {
    public static void hang1()
    {
        using SqlConnection oConnection = applib.getConnection() // returns an open connectin
        {
            using SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY 00:01:00", oConnection)
                oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // unplug cable between hub and database server when in this call and this call never returns
        }
     }

     public static void hang2()
     {
            using SqlCommand oTCmd = new SqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE", oConnection)
                oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using oTransaction = new SqlClient.SqlTransaction
            {

            using SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT max(id) FORM Table1")
            {
               oCmd.Transaction = oTransaction;
               oCmd.ExecuteScaler();
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
               // Disconnect the cable between the hub and the application server here
               // Now table Table1 is locked and will remain locked until the transaction
               // is manually killed from the database server.
               oCmd.ExecuteScaler();
            }
            }
      }
 }
```

We are seeking a solution to detect the transaction is stuck without having to set a timeout on it. If I were designing my own TCP/IP protocol, I'd design a heartbeat into it so that no response for a sufficient number of seconds = conclude dead, bail out, clean up. I'd like a way to accomplish the same idea, that is turn the quiet hang into a noisy crash so the cleanup code can clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists. it is called keep-alive.

See the following for information:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/03/09/546852.aspx?Redirected=true
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137983?sd=RMVP&fr=1

SQL Server will probe connections with KeepAlive packets and should detect quickly within a few minutes if the client is no longer present.

However this doesn't help you - you want the client to send keepalives to make sure the server is still beavering away.

There seems to be no supported way of doing this. If you wanted to enable TCP KeepAlives on your client socket you would have to use Reflection or unsafe code to locate the actual TCP Socket and use WSAIoctl to enable keepalives. A probably better solution is given in my other answer.

Comment: Well that's most of the answer. Now how to set keepalive on the client-side connection will finish it.

Comment: @Joshua, turns out that it is only sent by the server, not the client.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer as it is half the answer and the other half does not exist and any way of making it exist would involve a great deal of hackery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion.

On the SQL Server implement a proc called `CheckConnection(@spid int)`, which will report the status of the connection in some way. You can find this information from either `master.sys.sysprocesses` or the newer information schema views.

Something like this:

```
create proc CheckConnection(@spidToCheck int)
as
begin

    select 
        spcheck.spid, spcheck.blocked, 
        spcheck.lastwaittype, 
        (select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases sd where sd.dbid = spcheck.dbid) as database_name,
        spcheck.physical_io, 
        spcheck.memusage,
        spcheck.login_time,
        spcheck.last_batch, 
        spcheck.open_tran,
        spcheck.status,
        case 
        when spcheck.spid = spcurrent.spid
        then 'Same Connection'
        when 
        spcheck.net_library = spcurrent.net_library
        and spcheck.net_address = spcurrent.net_address
        and spcheck.sid = spcurrent.sid
        and spcheck.hostprocess = spcurrent.hostprocess
        then 'Same Client'
        else 'Different Client'
        end as client_status
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses spcheck
    inner join master.dbo.sysprocesses spcurrent
    on spcheck.spid = @spidToCheck and spcurrent.spid = @@spid



end
```

Before executing a long-running process, you can find out the SPID of the connection object by executing `connection.ExecuteScalar("select @@SPID as SPID");`. You can then use a separate connection to monitor every few minutes whether the SPID is still live and still has the same client. (Checking the client is the same is necessary because the SPID will be reused once closed).

Comment: Unfortunately, the application's runas user can't make use of master.dob.sysprocesses (it sees a mockup containing only itself).

Comment: @joshua, put the proc in master, and grant exec to public. Then it will work. (Make sure you are sysadmin when you do it).

Comment: doesn't get me out of having to ask for sa rights during upgrade, which we don't make a habit of after too many service calls